# Hierarchically grouping column values in text file

Tags: python, grouping

Is there a way to group values in a text file by a column?
I have a text file with values like

```
a,b,c
a,x,y
a,z,m
b,x,y
b,z,m
```

and need the values grouped on the unique first column like below.

```
a, b;x;z, c;y;m 
b, x;z, y;m
```

Comment: Do each line have exactly 3 columns?

Comment: It's a "text file" so you can just print what you want, so "Yes, you can print whatever you want."  However, if you want to put structure into the text file in a way that you can get it back later, you might consider changing the file to json. You can storing the records in a dict, using the first column as the key, and read/write that dict.

Comment: Also looking at the structure of content in the file, it looks like he wants to store the data as `csv`. In that case, it is better to have the first column as a header that describes the label of data each column contains.

Comment: @anil If my solution solved your issue kindly mark it as accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using pandas

myFile.txt

```
a,b,c
a,x,y
a,z,m
b,x,y
b,z,m
```

```
import pandas as pd
with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as xf:
    data = xf.read()
    print("Input data", data, sep='\n')
d = [values.split(',') for values in data.split('\n') if values != ""]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns = list('ABC'))
result = df.groupby(['A']).sum()
result = result.applymap(lambda x: ';'.join(x))
print("\nSolution", result, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
Input data
a,b,c
a,x,y
a,z,m
b,x,y
b,z,m


Solution
       B      C
A              
a  b;x;z  c;y;m
b    x;z    y;m
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file has only three columns each line,

```py
s1, s2, s3 = set(), set(), set()
with open('file.txt') as txt_file:
    lines = txt_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        c1, c2, c3 = line.split(',')
        s1.add(c1)
        s2.add(c2)
        s3.add(c3)

col1 = ';'.join(s1)
col2 = ';'.join(s2)
col3 = ';'.join(s3)

print("{}, {}, {}".format(col1, col2, col3))
```

So if the content of the file `file.txt` is:

```
a,b,c
a,x,y
a,z,m
```

The output:

```
a, b;z;x, y;m;c
```

Comment: The first column also has different values and needs to be grouped according to the value in the first column. 

a,b,c

a,x,y

a,z,m

b,x,y

b,z,m

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about formatting with semicolons and commas, a simple way is to group them in a dictionary:

```
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    dic = {}
    for line in lines:
        lst = line.strip().split(',')
        dic[lst[0]] = dic.get(lst[0], []) + lst[1:]

print(dic)
# {'a': ['b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'm'], 'b': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'm']}
```